# Visual studio extension, Background workers and UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Today I was refactoring some code in a visual studio extension project (for vs 2013) and I came across something weird.

In the code there is a background worker that executes a long lasting task. Inside the `dowork` event code there where calls to UI components of visual studio. To my surprise this code executed without exceptions. Am I outdated when thinking that UI updates could only be done in the `progresschanged` and `doworkcomplete` event?

Suprised as I was I tried executing the below code inside a Visual Studio (2013) extension project:

```
 private void StartAJob()
        {
            BackgroundWorker bgWork = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgWork.DoWork += Work;
            bgWork.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        private void Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var statusBar = (IVsStatusbar)GetService(typeof(SVsStatusbar));
            statusBar.Progress(1, 1, "Starting a job...", 0, 2);
            //do something that that takes a while
            statusBar.Progress(1, 1, "A little longer...", 1, 2);
            //do something else
            statusBar.Progress(1, 1, "Done!", 2, 2);
            MessageBox.Show("yay?");
        }
```

Does this mean I can savely executing interface code in a dowork event now (they always told me not to). Or is this some visual studio magic that resolves the exception somewhere far away from my code.

Comment: Just guessing, but could be that VS components are written to check whether the call needs to be synchronized to UI thread (e.g. like you would check with `InvokeRequired`)

Comment: Agree with previous comment. Most likely there's synchronization code. This isn't unique - e.g., WPF bindings can do synchronization for you.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I was thinking it would be along those lines. But I could find nothing to support it the theory.

Comment: @Dennis That would make sense. Isn't the VS interface written in WPF?

Comment: @NickOtten: I don't think so. VS is a sort of Frankenstein, having native and managed components. Some of them, probably, were written using WPF, but only *some*...

Comment: Good deal of UI since VS2010 is written in WPF, there is series of blog posts from Rico Mariani who lead the effort: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/10/19/my-history-of-visual-studio-part-10-final.aspx

Comment: More references: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/16/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You Can use the interface within the background worker, however you should check for

> InvokeRequired

When you're touching any UI from the background worker as it may be running on a separate thread to the UI thread.Example:

```
delegate void ProgressMessageCallback(string message);

    private void ProgressMessage(string message)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            ProgressMessageCallback d = new ProgressMessageCallback(ProgressMessage);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { message });
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblProgressMessage.Text = message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `InvokeRequired` doesn't help here. OP call VS automation interface, not a winforms control.

Comment: I'm aware of this and normally I would use the progresschanged and doworkcomplete event to update the interface. However now it appears to be working in the dowork event and I'm curious as to why.